# Perform GET request before component initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I have template code like this:

```
 <li *ngIf="isRoot() || isSoftware()">
```

Also i have this functions in my components code:

```
isRoot() {
    return this.service.Level == 'Root';
}

isSoftwareOnly() {
    return this.service.ServiceType == 'Software';
}
```

this.service gets by HTTP request.
How can I get request before template starts render? Now `isRoot()` and `isSoftware()` always return false, because this.service.Level and this.service.ServiceType are *undefined*

Comment: First, don't bind to functions, it's a bad practice because the functions are called every single angular check. Bind to variable or observables instead. To answer your question, learn more about life cycle here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways:

First (quickest): Use `constructor` of your component (let's say that you have `fetchData` method in your service to make an http request:

```
 export class Component {
     constructor(private service: MyService) {
          this.service.fetchData();
     }
 }
```

Second (slower): Use `ngOnInit` hook - data will be fetched in the same moment when initialization of view starts.

Third: Use `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook (in my opinion this is not best practice in your usecase) - according to documentation:

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
>   Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

[More about lifecycle hooks in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to check before a component initialization, the best way to perform that is Guards mechanism ([guide here](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)). To create a guard just create a class implementing CanActivate interface. The canActivate method of your class should return an Observable that tells the router if it can load a route.

So your guard will ensure your GET XHR have returned before activating the route containing your component.

something like ( view doc [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) )

```
@Injectable()
class CanActivateCheckServiceState implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private myService: <YourService>) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.myService.<yourGetMethod>
         .map(() => return true)
         .catch(() => return false)
  }
}
```

Then use it in your routing config:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '<yourPath>',
        component: <yourComponent>,
        canActivate: [CanActivateCheckServiceState]
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [CanActivateCheckServiceState, <yourService>]
})
class YourModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you entire template in an ng-container and have a flag in your component that is set to true once the data has loaded:

```
export class MyComponent {
   dataHasLoaded: boolean = false;

   ngOnInit() {
       this.loadData();
   }

   loadData() {
   // send http-request
   this.httpService.getData().subscribe(() => {
       this.dataHasLoaded = true;
   })
```

In your template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataHasLoaded">
    <!-- the rest of your HTML -->
</ng-container>
```

This way you html will only start rendering once you have your data.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called AFTER view initialization.

Comment: The link that you posted yourself clearly states that AfterViewInit happens much later then OnInit https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I did not mention anywhere about `afterViewInit` hook. The question is how to fetch data, before initialization start.

Comment: The question is about 'before template starts render'

Comment: yup. And `ngOnInit` happens after template starts to render... Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.